# MissingMethodException in JSON.Net in Unity3D webplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm serializing object using JSON.Net 5.0r6 on Unity3D, dotnet 2 version. I can run it fine in the Webplayer mode in Editor build, but when I deploy to Webplayer. I get a missing exception. I can get the same code to run fine on Android (without stripping) so it's not the code side.

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<System.String,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty>..ctor'.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract..ctor (System.Type underlyingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetContractSafe (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, System.Type type, Formatting formatting, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, Formatting formatting, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: ive got some code that does raw byte array packing which is pretty clean if you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Found another similar problem, seems to be Unity3D screwup again

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/133505-webplayer-and-System-Collections-ObjectModel-KeyedCollection

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is a problem with the use of `KeyedCollection` (originally in the mscorlib) that is implemented in JSON.Net.

The solution for me was to replace the whole implementation with [LitJson.dll](http://lbv.github.io/litjson/)

The only two methods that actually I use from JSON.Net are

```
    //JSON.Net
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonSring);
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
```

and you could easily change them with

```
    //LitJson
    JsonMapper.ToObject<YourClass>(jsonSring);
    JsonMapper.ToJson(yourObject);
```